# How to use Camera.cullingMask to selectively render certain objects?

Tags: unity, c#, rendering

The [documentation of this method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-cullingMask.html) doesn't provide any examples of implementing it. I don't understand how it works or even how I should use it to only render particular objects while not rendering others.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Edit > Project Settings > Tags and Layers > Layers and [create a layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/create-layers.html) called something like "Invisible".
2. Select the object you don't want the camera to draw. Set its layer to your newly-created "Invisible" layer using the drop-down at the top of the inspector.

   You can also set [gameObject.layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-layer.html) in code, using [LayerMask.NameToLayer()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.NameToLayer.html) to get the corresponding layer index integer for a given layer name.
3. Select the camera. Set its culling mask in the inspector to have a checkmark beside all layers you want to see, and no check beside the "Invisible" layer.

   You can also set this through code. The culling mask is just a bitmask, where the \$i^{th}\$ bit is 1 if the camera should draw layer \$i\$. [LayerMask.GetMask()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.GetMask.html) lets you provide a list of layer names to include in the mask, if you don't want to do the bit-twiddling yourself.